# String.Replace does not seem to replace brackets with empty string

Tags: c#, string

The following bit of C# code does not seem to do anything:

```
String str = "{3}";
str.Replace("{", String.Empty);
str.Replace("}", String.Empty);

Console.WriteLine(str);
```

This ends up spitting out: {3}.  I have no idea why this is.  I do this sort of thing in Java all the time.  Is there some nuance of .NET string handling that eludes me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948978/string-replace-not-working. This one came first, but the other has a clearer title.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The String class is [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object); `str.Replace` will not alter `str`, it will return a new string with the result. Try this one instead:

```
String str = "{3}";
str = str.Replace("{", String.Empty);
str = str.Replace("}", String.Empty);

Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Answer (score 8):

String is immutable; you can't change an instance of a string.  Your two Replace() calls do nothing to the original string; they return a modified string.  You want this instead:

```
String str = "{3}";
str = str.Replace("{", String.Empty);
str = str.Replace("}", String.Empty);

Console.WriteLine(str);
```

It works this way in Java as well.

Answer (score 7):

Replace actually does not modify the string instance on which you call it. It just returns a modified copy instead.

Try this one:

```
String str = "{3}";
str = str.Replace("{", String.Empty);
str = str.Replace("}", String.Empty);

Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Answer (score 6):

Str.Replace returns a new string. So, you need to use it as follows:

```
String str = "{3}";
str = str.Replace("{", String.Empty);
str = str.Replace("}", String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to do:

```
String str = "{3}";
str = str.Replace("{", String.Empty);
str = str.Replace("}", String.Empty);

Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Look at the [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) reference:

> Return Value Type: System.String
>
> A String equivalent to this instance but
> with all instances of oldValue
> replaced with newValue.

Answer (score 5):

The Replace function returns the modified string, so you have to assign it back to your `str` variable.

```
String str = "{3}";
str = str.Replace("{", String.Empty);
str = str.Replace("}", String.Empty);

Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe that str.Replace returns a value which you must assign to your variable.  So you will need to do something like:

```
String str = "{3}";
str = str.Replace("{", String.Empty);
str = str.Replace("}", String.Empty);

Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Replace` method *returns* a string with the replacement.  What I think you're looking for is this:

```
str = str.Replace("{", string.Empty);
str = str.Replace("}", string.Empty);

Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Answer (score 3):

Besides all of the suggestions so far - you could also accomplish this without changing the value of the original string by using the replace functions inline in the output...

```
String str = "{3}";

Console.WriteLine(str.Replace("{", String.Empty).Replace("}", String.Empty));
```