# c# replace string function not returning expected results

Tags: c#, string

```
string message = CommonFunctions.SanitiseInput(context.Request.QueryString["msg"]);
```

And the function is defined as:

```
// Sanitise input
public static string SanitiseInput(string inputText)
{
    string cleanedString = inputText;

    cleanedString.Replace("<","&lt;");      // No code
    cleanedString.Replace(">", "&gt;");
    cleanedString.Replace("&", "&amp;");    // No query string breaks

    return cleanedString;
}
```

Given input `"<b>rg</b>"` this returns the same, and not `"&lt;b&gt;rg&lt;/b&gt;"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [String.Replace does not seem to replace brackets with empty string...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936847/string-replace-does-not-seem-to-replace-brackets-with-empty-string)

Comment: just a note: it seems to me that you're basically duplicating the builtin HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode function (maybe it's just because you've simplified your scenario to explain your question)

Comment: Note that you have to replace `&` before replacing `<` and `>`, otherwise `<` will end up as `&amp;lt;` and `>` will end up as `&amp;gt;`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Replace` function in C# does not modify the string itself - it returns a modified version of the string.

Try this:

```
public static string SanitiseInput(string inputText)
{
    string cleanedString = inputText;

    cleanedString = cleanedString.Replace("<","&lt;");      // No code
    cleanedString = cleanedString.Replace(">", "&gt;");
    cleanedString = cleanedString.Replace("&", "&amp;");    // No query string breaks

    return cleanedString;
}
```

For `"<b>rg</b>"` this will give you `"&amp;lt;b&amp;gt;rg&amp;lt;/b&amp;gt;"`. To fix up the unnecessary conversions to `"&amp;"`, move the third replacement to before the other two, which will give you the result you are expecting.

Comment: In any case you probably want to use [`System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx), or if you're running with the .NET Client profile you can get equivalent code from Microsoft's [AntiXSS](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=051ee83c-5ccf-48ed-8463-02f56a6bfc09&displaylang=en) library, or you could copy the HtmlEncode code into your project from Reflector

Comment: @Rup Agreed, and I upvoted the answer that suggested that, as well as answering the problem with the given code and voting to close as an exact duplicate... I feel like I've done too much work here.

Answer (score 3):

You should use HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmlencode.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `cleanedString = cleanedString.Replace("<","&lt;");` etc.