# Replace value in string c# not working

Tags: c#, string

```
            <tbody><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_header">
                <td id="fixedStartDate" class="resultsSubHeader">
                    Fixed Start 
                </td>
                <td id="fixedEndDate" class="resultsSubHeader">
                    Fixed End 
                </td>
                <td style="display: none;" id="floatingStartDate" class="resultsSubHeader">
                    Floating Start                         
                </td>
                <td style="display: none;" id="floatingEndDate" class="resultsSubHeader">
                    Floating End
                </td>
                <td class="resultsSubHeader">
                    Notional
                </td>
                <td class="resultsSubHeader">
                    Drop
                </td>
            </tr>
        <tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Apr-2011</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">16-May-2011</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">16-May-2011</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Jun-2011</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Jun-2011</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Jul-2011</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Jul-2011</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">15-Aug-2011</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">15-Aug-2011</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Sep-2011</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Sep-2011</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Oct-2011</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Oct-2011</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Nov-2011</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Nov-2011</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Dec-2011</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Dec-2011</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">17-Jan-2012</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">17-Jan-2012</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Feb-2012</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Feb-2012</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Mar-2012</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Mar-2012</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">16-Apr-2012</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">16-Apr-2012</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-May-2012</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-May-2012</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Jun-2012</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Jun-2012</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">16-Jul-2012</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">16-Jul-2012</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Aug-2012</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Aug-2012</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Sep-2012</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Sep-2012</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">15-Oct-2012</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">15-Oct-2012</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Nov-2012</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Nov-2012</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Dec-2012</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Dec-2012</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Jan-2013</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Jan-2013</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Feb-2013</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Feb-2013</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Mar-2013</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Mar-2013</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">15-Apr-2013</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">15-Apr-2013</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-May-2013</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-May-2013</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Jun-2013</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Jun-2013</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">15-Jul-2013</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">15-Jul-2013</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Aug-2013</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Aug-2013</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">16-Sep-2013</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">16-Sep-2013</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">15-Oct-2013</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">15-Oct-2013</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Nov-2013</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Nov-2013</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">16-Dec-2013</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">16-Dec-2013</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Jan-2014</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Jan-2014</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Feb-2014</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Feb-2014</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Mar-2014</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Mar-2014</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Apr-2014</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Apr-2014</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-May-2014</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-May-2014</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">16-Jun-2014</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">16-Jun-2014</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Jul-2014</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Jul-2014</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Aug-2014</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Aug-2014</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">15-Sep-2014</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">15-Sep-2014</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Oct-2014</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Oct-2014</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Nov-2014</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Nov-2014</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">15-Dec-2014</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">15-Dec-2014</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Jan-2015</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Jan-2015</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">17-Feb-2015</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">17-Feb-2015</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">16-Mar-2015</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">16-Mar-2015</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Apr-2015</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Apr-2015</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-May-2015</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-May-2015</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">15-Jun-2015</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">15-Jun-2015</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Jul-2015</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Jul-2015</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Aug-2015</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Aug-2015</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Sep-2015</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Sep-2015</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Oct-2015</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Oct-2015</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">16-Nov-2015</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">16-Nov-2015</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Dec-2015</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Dec-2015</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Jan-2016</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Jan-2016</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">16-Feb-2016</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">16-Feb-2016</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Mar-2016</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr><tr class="ind_calc_preview_schedule_row amortizationschedulepreviewrow"><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Mar-2016</td><td class="ind_calc_date_column">14-Apr-2016</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$10,000,000.00</td><td class="ind_calc_curr_column">$0.00</td></tr></tbody>
```

So this is actually a string I have in c#, and I want to replace `tbody` with `table`, so I'm trying to do it like this:

```
_viewPath.Replace("tbody", "table");
```

But it isn't working. Why?

Comment: Can you show more code?  For example, are you assigning the string returned by Replace to a string variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# replace string function not returning expected results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076812/c-replace-string-function-not-returning-expected-results)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should do:

```
_viewPath = _viewPath.Replace("tbody", "table");
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `string.Replace` does not modify the string, it returns a new one

```
_viewPath = _viewPath.Replace("tbody", "table");
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable. That means you don't modify them - .Replace returns a NEW string. Try this:

```
_viewPath = _viewpath.Replace("tbody", "table");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should save the result of Replace: `_viewPath = _viewPath.Replace("tbody", "table");`

Answer (score 0):

`Replace` is a **function** actually, and does **return** the results. You have to do it this way :

```
var Result = _viewPath.Replace("tbody", "table");
```

where Results contains the result of the transformation.