# Set of quotes string replace in C#

Tags: c#, escaping, str-replace, double-quotes, single-quotes

I would like to transforme this string `'"` into this string `>>`.

I have already read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393879/double-quote-string-replace-in-c-sharp).

Here is what I've tried:

```
string str = "'"";
str = str.Replace("'\"",">>");
```

It is not throwing any error but doesn't do anything neither. Thank you very much.

Comment: Assign the value back to the original string `str = str.Replace("'\"",">>");`

Comment: The code you've provided at the moment won't compile. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String.Replace does not seem to replace brackets with empty string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936847/string-replace-does-not-seem-to-replace-brackets-with-empty-string)

Comment: also, editing the code like you just did actually solves the issue

Comment: That what I wanted to write sorry. I edited my question.

Comment: Your question needs the first string changing to this `string str = "'\"";`, otherwise the code works fine.

Comment: My string is actually coming from a filter in a spgridview but I don't want to overload the thread with unnecessary details like adding the whole class that is using my code. That why the string with the double quotes is assigned to my variable that way.
But you're right, such an assignment will fail because the seconde double quotes ending the string. Nevermind, it's not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

`string.Replace` returns a new string since strings are immutable in C#.

Simply do `str = str.Replace("'\"",">>");`

Comment: I edited my question. It was just a mistake of course need to asign it back or else it wont work. But that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: I think you have an error where you try to replace `'\"` with `>>` ... try just `\"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Good Idea, but I really need to replace the two characters at the same time. ie the ' and the ".

Comment: that's a different question, is it the string `'"` or each individual character that could be apart?

Comment: It's '" exactly as you edited my question. So any other suggestion?

Comment: @ameliapond Equalsk has already answered this in a comment. From a file or outside data object, you may be receiving ('") literally and the code would work. But in the code you posted above, to be able to test this you would also need to escape the " like you did in the replace method. string str = "'""; would not allow you to compile and test it. You need to test it against "'\"" (that's " ' \" " without the spaces between).